# Hide placeholder if it has been shown before

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, placeholder

So I'm trying to write some code to hide a piece of javascript in a placeholder. The idea is to hide it if it has been shown once. My code looks like this:

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LoadScript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
       javascript function
    </script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I have an idea of using session and the visible state for the placeholder but can't really figure out the logic. Here's what I'm trying to work with:

```
Session["Script"] = LoadScript.Visible;
 this.LoadScript.Visible = false;
```

Could someone figure out a way to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Session["scriptRan"] != null) 
{
    this.LoadScript.Visible = false; 
}
else
{
    Session["scriptRan"] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Visible property is just changing CSS proprty of visibility. It will not stop your code working. 
But:

```
if(Session["run"]==null)
   //change visibility
else
   //also change visibility but make it different.
```